# c 2d array scanf problems

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I can't figure out why my 2d array seems to be off by 1 positions. when scanning characters, it would seem the first value is being missed. so what should be array[0][0] is not getting registered, and the value that should be array[0][1] is array [0][0].

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
        {
        char a[2][4];
        //char ch;
        printf("enter a string please");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

                for (int x = 0 ; x < 5; x++)
                {
                        scanf("%c", &a[i][x]);
                        printf("%d",i);
                        printf("%d",x);
                        //scanf("%c", &a[i][x]);
                        printf("%c", a[i][x]);
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
        printf("%c\n",a[0][4]);
        printf("%c\n",a[1][4]);
        printf("%c\n",a[2][4]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                {
                        printf("%c", a[i][x]);
                }
                printf("\n");

        }

        }
```

Output:
enter a string please!@@@@@#####BBBBB
00@
01@
02@
03@
04@
10#
11#
12#
13#
14#
20B
21B
22B
23B
24B
"#"
"B"
"B"
"@@@@#"
"####B"
"BBBBB"
want it to be:
"@@@@@"
"#####"
"BBBBB"

Comment: Review `char a[2][4]; ...  for (int x = 0 ; x < 5; x++) ...    scanf("%c", &a[i][x]);`.  I would expect `x < 4` (and `i < 2`).

Comment: I totally didn't grasp that when determining the arrays length and depth it doesn't count zero. so I thought a[2][4] was actually a[3][5]

Thank you!!!

Comment: @JamesElliot You defined a 2*4 array but then try to read 3*5 values in it.

Comment: Just caught that thanks so much everyone!!

Comment: Instead of hard coding 2, 4 , etc. throughout code, use `#dfine ROW 2  #define COL 4` and then use `for (int x = 0; x < COL; x++)` etc.

Comment: regarding: `for (int x = 0 ; x < 5; x++)`  the valid range for second index is 0...3 in the array: `char a[2][4];`.  Therefore, the posted code contains undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c\n",a[0][4]);`  this is accessing beyond the end of the row in the array.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`  this is accessing rows 0,,1, 2 but there are only 2 rows, so this is accessing beyond the end of the array, which results in undefined behavior

Comment: in general, the valid indexes into an array are: 0...(number of elements in array -1)

Comment: regarding statements like: `scanf("%c", &a[i][x]);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'.  For the current statement,  any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  BTW: do you want to include the trailing '\n' in the array.

Comment: what do you plan on displaying when the user did not input enough characters to fill the array?